# COUNT with RANK mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

From my database I want to get the lastname of employee, the number of employees who earn higher than him, and then rank the employee's salary in descending order; with the highest earning employee as zero. Here is how I have done it:

```
SELECT 0+COUNT(b.salary) rank
, a.lname
, a.salary
, COUNT(*) AS employee_count
FROM employee a LEFT OUTER JOIN employee b
ON a.salary<b.salary
GROUP BY a.salary, a.lname
ORDER BY salary DESC
```

And the result is shown like this:

[image]

So far so good. Except, Borg shouldn't be even there. Because no one is earning more than him. Now this happened because of using LEFT OUTER JOIN. I tried using INNER JOIN but it gives syntax error. So the question is how can I make INNER JOIN work with this?

Comment: Employee count for Borg is wrong, right?

Comment: Yeah, Borg should not show up, or it show up but the value for count should be zero.

Comment: @Modaresi If LEFT JOIN works well, what about add `WHERE b.salary IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: What kind of syntax error you got with `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: works fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36744/2

Comment: was it a typo? did you use INNER OUTER JOIN perhaps?

Comment: I think you are right, I must have, because I cannot reproduce the same error, even though I tried it several times before and every time it gave an error! Though, is there a way to show Borg and have his rank shown as 0, rather than omitting him completely.

Comment: Your example has him with a rank of 0, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, but then the count is one too, instead of 0. So I meant like my example show Borg but with correct counting.

Comment: In OP's example, b.salary for Borg is NULL, COUNT(NULL) is 0. and COUNT(*) is 1.

Comment: and what does count in this case mean? I think `rank` means number of employees with the salary greater than him

Comment: No, rank is given to the person with highest earning. That's why Borg is 0, while Zelaya is 5 because she earns the least. employee count is the number of employees earning higher than him. That's why Borg must be 0 because no one earns higher than him.

Comment: if it makes you happy use `COUNT(b.lname) AS employee_count`, but this will be literally the same as your rank column, which does represent the "number of employees earning higher than him"

Comment: What about you have two people on top? Say borg 55000 and zerg 55000 what would be the result?

Comment: @JorgeCampos there is a sql fiddle. try it and see

Comment: I already did it but I wonder if for the OP the column `rank` has to continue from the second position and not from the N-people that has the bigger salary. As here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2850c/1

Comment: @Modaresi OK, I think I know what you are after. Your employee_count should be: `COUNT(DISTINCT b.salary) AS employee_count`. Explanation: this way you will find the number of salaries that are greater than yours. [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2850c/4)

Comment: Yeah, I think now you know what I am looking for. I did try your statement but it throws error# 1064.

Comment: quick search shows that this error is most likely caused by: `maybe you forgot to add ";"`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to eliminate the top value:

```
SELECT *
FROM (    
    SELECT 0+COUNT(b.salary) rank
        , a.lname
        , a.salary
        , COUNT(*) AS employee_count
    FROM employee a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN employee b
        ON a.salary < b.salary
    GROUP BY a.salary, a.lname
    ORDER BY salary DESC
) T1
WHERE T1.rank > 0
```